# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and $f$ is continuous is $f_n$ continuous for all $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

As the problem title states, if $f_n \rightarrow f$ converges uniformly and $f$ is continuous is $f_n$ continuous for all $n$?

Comment: Fix a bounded but otherwise arbitrary function $\phi$ and define $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\phi$. Then $f_n \to 0$ uniformly but $f_n$ can be made as badly discontinuous as possible.

Comment: Convergence is a property of the tail of a sequence, you can alter the members of the sequence however you like, as long as you keep the tail the same, and the sequence will still converge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, consider the sequence of functions
$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1/n & \text{if $x=0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Then $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, and while $0$ is continuous, none of the $f_n$ are.

Comment: Thanks! If $f(x)$ is continuous is $f_n=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$ continuous? (I can open a new question if you are not comfortable answering this in the comment section).

Comment: Yes, because that would be the composition of two continuous functions, $f$ and the function $x\mapsto x + \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

No. Simply knowing that a sequence (of anything) converges (in any sense) to a given limit tells us nothing about individual terms of the sequence. If $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then you can choose any integer $m$ and replace $f_m$ by any function you want, without changing the fact that the sequence converges to $f$.